# Clear picked date in calendarDatePicker control from XAML

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Is it possible to clear a picked date in CalendarDatePicker control in XAML? I have the following code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10" Spacing="32">
   <TextBlock x:Name="date_identified_label"  Text="Identified:">
   </TextBlock>
   <CalendarDatePicker x:Name="date_identified_picker">
   </CalendarDatePicker>
</StackPanel>
```

This will help me resetting the date after the control is disabled and enabled again. Otherwise when I disable and then enable it again the old date is still shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a property  and wire it to "Date" on your calendar control like below

```
<CalendarDatePicker x:Name="date_identified_picker"
Date="{Binding yourPropertyName,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

and also in order to clear calendar date you need to explicitly Set your Calendar Date property to null whenever you are disabling your control. so that whenever your control is re-enabled, it will allow you to select a date again